# Comparing list values and select maximum from each day - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6. I have a below list(capturing start time through a json object) and would like to capture the most recent date/time value in the list for each day.

`mytimelist =[2020-05-30T19:21:36.124Z, 2020-05-31T10:34:06.137Z, 2020-05-31T17:14:06.117Z,2020-05-31T23:06:21.131Z, 2020-06-01T19:21:36.108Z, 2020-06-01T21:55:11.137Z]`

I would want the below list.

`myfinallist = [2020-05-30T19:21:36.124Z, 2020-05-31T23:06:21.131Z, 2020-06-01T21:55:11.137Z]`

Could anybody please help me here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help to share your code relavant to the question.

Comment: I had the use-case of fetching the AWS snapshots. I wanted to keep most recent one to avoid extra storage cost. Since, I am very new to Python, so I wasn't able to figure out a way to actually implement this. With the list, I can delete snapshots using delete API. Code for list:
`host = ' '  # AWS ElasticSearch Hostname here
path = '_snapshot/indexes-test/'
url = host + path
resp = get(url + '_all?pretty', auth=awsauth, headers=headers)
resp_json = resp.json()

snapshots_captured = resp_json['snapshots']

mytimelist = []
for i in snapshot_name:
 mytimelist.append(i['start_time']) `

Answer (score 1):

A solution could include [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools.

```
from itertools import groupby

mytimelist =['2020-05-30T19:21:36.124Z', '2020-05-31T10:34:06.137Z', '2020-05-31T17:14:06.117Z','2020-05-31T23:06:21.131Z', '2020-06-01T19:21:36.108Z', '2020-06-01T21:55:11.137Z']

for k, v in groupby(sorted(mytimelist), key=lambda x: x[:10]):
    print(list(v)[-1])

2020-05-30T19:21:36.124Z
2020-05-31T23:06:21.131Z
2020-06-01T21:55:11.137Z
```

**Update:** Sorted the datetime entries per `a'r`'s note below.

Comment: Take care here, as `groupby` requires the input to be sorted (similar to the unix `uniq` command).

Comment: @a'r Thanks for noting this. I made a change to the code to sort the list

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can get the dates as strings in Python?  Then you can use `datetime` to convert them into `datetime` objects, and loop over the unique dates, checking the max as you go.

```
import datetime as dt

mytimelist =['2020-05-30T19:21:36.124Z',
             '2020-05-31T10:34:06.137Z',
             '2020-05-31T17:14:06.117Z',
             '2020-05-31T23:06:21.131Z',
             '2020-06-01T19:21:36.108Z',
             '2020-06-01T21:55:11.137Z']

#see https://strftime.org/ for the syntax
date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
datetimes = [dt.datetime.strptime(t,date_format) for t in mytimelist]

output = {}
for time in datetimes:
    date = time.date()
    if date not in output:
        output[date] = time
    else:
        if time > output[date]:
            output[date] = time

for key in sorted(output.keys()):
    print(str(key) + ': ' + str(output[key]))
```

Output:

```
2020-05-30: 2020-05-30 19:21:36.124000
2020-05-31: 2020-05-31 23:06:21.131000
2020-06-01: 2020-06-01 21:55:11.137000
```